# Typescript definition to C# POCO generator

Tags: c#, typescript

- I've seen tools out there that does the reverse, i.e. from C# to Typescript.
  Is there any tools that transform Typescript definition to C#?

Such a tool seems possible since Typescript has a [compiler API that exposes the AST](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)

My main aim is to write my React components in Typescript, define its props, then have the props definition transformed into C# POCO. I would then populate data in POCO in my ASP.NET controller and pass it to my view into `Html.React`.

- Before embarking on writing a TS to C# transform, what alternatives will you suggest?

Comment: I haven't come across anything that does what you want, but it definitely is possible, as I have been able to write tools that generate code based off of TypeScript interfaces in the past.

Comment: @JoeSkeen anything on github that you can share?

Comment: unfortunately everything I've done with it is currently closed source for work.  Basically what it boiled down to was this: `require('typescript')`, `ts.createSourceFile(sourceFileName, sourceFileContents, ts.ScriptTarget.ES5)`, then recursively call `node.getChildren(file)` and you can inspect the members and types, then generate code from the results of that.  Of course, that worked with an older version of TS, but hopefully that could get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise serializing TypeScript files to XML then creating the POCO's from the XML (using Visual Studios XSD executable).
You could quite easily create a gulp task for this.

TypeScript to XML: https://github.com/weichx/cerialize

XML to C# POCO: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Cool, but seems to be serializing objects. Looks like there's Typescript interface to JSON schema generator, then JSON schema to C# generator. Thanks for the inspiration!